# Get context type of requested url using python

Tags: python

I am trying to get headers of url using python using http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ this tutorial. I am trying following code in python idle , I am getting following error,

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 375, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /user (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like github is denying you access to the requested page. Before attempting to request pages in python try typing them into the browser to see what is returned. When I did this I was returned some JSON stating

```
{
    "message": "Requires authentication",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

If you want to test your code and find headers of a webpage, try a publicly accessible webpage before delving into APIs.